# when manually inserting a document should I add _v?

Tags: mongoose

When I insert a new document manually (cli or gui), the _v Key is obviously not automatically added. Is this fine or should I also manually add _v:0 everytime ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey)

> The versionKey is a property set on each document when first created
> by Mongoose. This keys value contains the internal revision of the
> document. The name of this document property is configurable.

If a document is being created using mongoose, it automatically inserts the __v field in the document. You can change the name __v to __version if you want. I am not sure if you are creating the document using mongoose or directly inserting into MongoDB.

You can also disable the version key by setting it in schema as false. Check that too.